# Counter and show nft Candy machine v3

Tags: metaplex, candy-machine

Hello I’m using a repo of a Candy machine ui metaplex . And my knowledge do not permit me to add a counter for the remaining nft , and I wanted to show in a block the nft minted . Is there any documents here ? Thank you so much

I tried to use severals repositories to check into each code but it’s too hard to understand because each code fetch data differently.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which frameworks you are using. When using umi you can use fetchCandyMachine https://mpl-candy-machine-js-docs.vercel.app/functions/fetchCandyMachine.html

It returns a candy machine object with itemsLoaded (amount of NFTs in the cm) and itemsRedeemed (amount of NFTs minted)

Comment: i manage to show them in a div close to my mint block , seems ok  . Now is there any way to show the nft minted by the same fetching trick ?*

Comment: yes, you can fetch digital Assets. This would be better suited in a new question though.